# Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle, slow for view not for table (Excel VBA)

Tags: oracle, vba, odbc, ado

We are forced to use the Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle as our means of connecting Excel VBA over ADO to an Oracle 11GR2 database.

We have noticed it is incredibly slow returning data from a relatively simple view (the view executes quickly in SQL Developer)...but if we derive a table from the view results...and execute a query against the table, then Excel returns data in about 10 seconds.  It is returning 11,000 records.

When we are going through a view, we see the data starting to be returned (so the view has done its job and executed), but then to the point of the recordset copy into the worksheet completing - it takes 6 minutes.

Use the table derived from the view, and it takes 10 seconds.

I would love the luxury of using the oracle oledb driver (don't ask), but can't so need to resolve this if possible.

```
strConOracle = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
         "CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
         "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
         "(HOST=" & "myserver.mycompany.net" & ")(PORT=1524))" & _
         "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & SID & "))); uid=" & username & " ;pwd=" & password & ";"


'---  Now connection is open and you can use queries to execute them.
'---  It will be open till you close the connection

'sql = "Select * from TEMP_TABLE_FROM_MY_VIEW"   VERY FAST < 10 seconds 11,000 rows
sql = "Select * from MY_VIEW"
Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
Set rs = con.Execute(sql)

'6 minutes executing the view, with data seen in worksheet very quickly (view resolved)
Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

UPDATE:  It seems related to large character widths.  So we have varchar2(4000) fields, containing ~2-300 characters (we are replicating another data environment).  Oledb works fine, but this ODBC driver - it kills it.  We are casting to varchar2(300) to get better performance, but it is still slow (but an improvement).

Comment: If you execute `Select * from MY_VIEW` from the Oracle SQL client on the same workstation where the VBA code is running, do you get all results in 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes.  When I execute the view over oracle driver for OLEDB (working on my PC, but not guaranteed on rest of corporate platform)...again executing the view, 10 seconds...so it isn't the view specifically.

Comment: Have you tried `con.CursorLocation=adUseClient` before you open the connection ? Client side ADO cursors can be much faster.

Comment: Hi, yes have tried server and client side cursors, and with both have tried opening the connection as read only.  Makes no difference it seems.

Comment: Try `Select COUNT(*) from MY_VIEW` instead. This will return only one row but could well be as expensive to execute. Is it faster ?

Comment: Also (never tried this myself) you could try changing optimizer modes just after you connect. e.g. `con.Execute "alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE=RULE"` or `con.Execute "alter session set OPTIMIZER_MODE=ALL_ROWS"`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_VIEW performs well.  I don't think its view optimisation itself.  View executes quickly over OLEDB driver, and also directly in SQL Developer.

Comment: Before execute SQL 05/05/2015 10:39
After execute SQL 05/05/2015 10:48  Lag appears to be in the execution of the SQL not the copying?  But that is with a client side cursor so that probably includes copying dataset over to client.

Comment: Before copy from recordset 05/05/2015 11:08
After copy from recordset 05/05/2015 11:17  with server side client just pushes delay to copy from recordset vs query execution